# Is there any way to speed up SQLite Update command?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, xlrd

I am creating this table from another table then attempting to update the SQL table with information from an excel sheet. The update function is going incredibly slow, and I am hoping to find a way to increase the speed. Here is what I am using.

```
masterDBConn = sqlite3.connect('MasterDB.db')
masterCursor = masterDBConn.cursor()

masterCursor.execute('CREATE TABLE MasterV2 (InventoryNbr, IndexListID, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7)')
masterCursor.execute('INSERT INTO MasterV2 SELECT InventoryNbr, MAX(IndexListID), col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7 FROM Master GROUP BY InventoryNbr')
masterCursor.execute('CREATE INDEX InventoryNbrIndex ON MasterV2(InventoryNbr)')
masterDBConn.commit()


wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\Users\MasterDatabaseV2.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
start_time = time.time()
for row in range(1, ws.nrows):
    print('here1 ---%s seconds ---' % (time.time() - start_time))
    number= ws.cell_value(row, 7).split(',')
    number= [x.strip(' ') for x in number]
    for holl in number:
        print('here2 ---%s seconds ---' % (time.time() - start_time))
        if len(holl) > 3:
            col1 = str(ws.cell_value(row, 0)).strip('.0')[0:255]
            col2 = str(ws.cell_value(row, 1)).strip()[0:255]
            col3 = str(ws.cell_value(row, 2)).strip()[0:255]
            col4 = str(ws.cell_value(row, 3)).strip()[0:255]
            col5 = str(ws.cell_value(row, 4)).strip()[0:255]
            col6 = str(ws.cell_value(row, 5)).strip()[0:255]
            col7 = str(ws.cell_value(row, 6)).strip()[0:255]
            print('here3 ---%s seconds ---' % (time.time() - start_time))
            masterCursor.execute('UPDATE MasterV2 SET col1 = ?, col2 = ?, col3 = ?, col4 = ?, col5 = ?, col6 = ?, col7 = ?', (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7))
            print('here4 ---%s seconds ---' % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Here is the output of my time prints:

```
here1 ---0.003003358840942383 seconds ---
here2 ---0.003003358840942383 seconds ---
here3 ---0.003003358840942383 seconds ---
here4 ---1.7457876205444336 seconds ---
here1 ---1.7457876205444336 seconds ---
here2 ---1.7457876205444336 seconds ---
here3 ---1.7457876205444336 seconds ---
here4 ---2.5108072757720947 seconds ---
```

As you can see the Update statement is taking over half a second each time it executes, and i have about 20,000 rows I need to update information on. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I was missing a WHERE clause in my Update statement, and that resolved my issue.

Comment: Add a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Why build a second table with what looks like identical data? Create a view instead and query that.

Comment: I am building a new table because there might be up to 100 identical InventoryNbs and I would rather have the table be a list of just Distinct InventoryNbr's.

Comment: Your update modifies every row in the table each time it's called. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: @Shawn No, I added a where clause and it fixed my problem. Thanks

Comment: Also, `executemany()` will be faster still...

Comment: How does executemany() work when I am only sending data 1 line at a time in the for loop?